# My ajax code not working after i update jquery version to 3.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The ajax part of My program was running until I have used jquery version 1.7 as soon as I have update my jquery version to 3.3.1 I have attached ajax part of my code. And in php file I just use inset post method to get the data and just run a mysql query. And if the the found row number is 0 then echo no either yes.

Here the ajax code:

```
 $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "ajax.php",  
    data: "username="+ username,  
    success: function(msg){  
   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 

Then codes need to be run.

Then close all braces.
```

Comment: try jQuery instead of $

Comment: Provide full code of your jquery

Comment: Open your console, which errors/warnings do you see? Need more info.. Your code is incomplete also.

Comment: Documentation for `ajaxComplete` only talks about adding this handler to `document`, not sure if that is even supposed to work when you bind it to a specific HTML element …? And why are you binding this event only in the success callback of an AJAX call? This affects _all_ AJAX requests you make, so why did you not set this up before? And if you are executing the above code multiple times, you would add another complete handler.

Comment: Thanks! All of you for valuable suggestions. With your suggestion I have solved this issue by alternating the programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hope to help you.

### demo.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_REQUEST['username'])){
      echo $_REQUEST['username'];die;
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "<site_url>/demo.php",  
        data: "username=hello",  
        success: function(msg){  
          alert(msg); 
        }});
    });
   $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 
          alert("ajaxComplete");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Call Ajax Demo</button>
<body>
</html>
```